# How do I use ranges in case statement c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I want to know what I am doing wrong here:

```
string grade;
switch (percentageMark)
{
    case (90 - 100):
        grade = "A*";
        break;
    case (80 - 89):
        grade = "A";
        break;
    case (70 - 79):
        grade = "B";
        break;
    case (60 - 69):
        grade = "C";
        break;
    case (50 - 59):
        grade = "D";
        break;
    case (40 - 49):
        grade = "E";
        break;
    case (0 - 39):
        grade = "U";
        break;
}
```

I get errors saying that "The label 'case -9:' already occurs in this switch statement", but only at cases 3, 4, 5 and 6. Could someone tell me why I am getting these errors

Comment: use if statement here

Comment: The short answer is you can't. There is no ranges in C# case statements

Comment: This isn't doing what you think it's doing. That first one for example compiles to `case (-10):`

Comment: @sab669 - I got that from the question.  The compiler error quoted: `The label 'case -9:' already occurs in this switch statement` seems to indicate that this isn't just pseudocode.  Maybe I'm just reading it too literally?

Comment: @theB Nope, you're right. I was reading on my phone and missed the last sentence detailing his errors, so I thought it was just psuedocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have range in case.

you have to use multiple case like:

```
case 90:
case 91:
case 92:
case 93:
case 94:
...
...
case:100:
        grade = "A*";
```

or alternatively you can have if statements for applying range :

```
if(percentageMark >= 90 && percentageMark <=100)
   grade = "A*";
```

Comment: You really don't want to type out 100 cases.

Comment: But there is no shortcut available sadly

Answer (score 3):

As Ehsan already pointed that you cannot use range inside case. And in your case it looks like it would be better to use `if..else` instead of `switch case`.

Like this:

```
if(percentageMark >= 90 && percentageMark <=100)
   grade = "A*";
else if(percentageMark >= 80)
   grade = "A";
else if(percentageMark >= 70)
   grade = "B";
else if(percentageMark >= 60)
   grade = "C";
else if(percentageMark >= 50)
   grade = "D";
else if(percentageMark >= 40)
   grade = "E";
else
   grade = "U";
```

Comment: `&& value <= 89` as well as `&& value <= 79` etc. are *redundant*: just drop them

Comment: @DmitryBychenko:- Thanks for pointing that. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, C#'s switches do not support ranges.

You will have to use if's and else if's.

For your code this would be something like this:

```
if (value >= 90 && value <= 100)
{
    // Your code
}
else if (value >= 80 && value < 90)
{
    // Your code
}
else if (value >= 70 && value < 80)
{
    // Your code
}
```

etc.

Of course if you want to use a switch and the grade is always a value between 0 and 100 then you could use this switch:

```
switch(grade)
{
    case grade > 90:
        // A*
        break;
    case grade > 80:
        // B
        break;
}
```

etc.

Comment: `&& value < 90` as well as `&& value < 80` are *redundant*: just drop them